# How to turn off animation when sliding a Slider?

Tags: animation, swiftui, charts, slider

I have an AnimatedChart() that gets generated based on the value of the slider. The problem is that it generates all along the slide of the slider and not just when it reached its final resting position.

I have seen reference to options like isContinuous or animated.

What is the best way to stop the slider calling the AnimatedChart() routine when it is in transit?

```
var body: some View {

    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 12) {
         AnimatedChart()
    }

    HStack {
         Slider(value: $daySlider, in: 0...364)
         .accentColor(Color.blue)
    }
}
```

Comment: This may help: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/slider/init(value:in:oneditingchanged:) You should be able to use the onEditingChanged closure to only change the state that your chart shows when the user finishes sliding. I mean you have one state for the slider, and one for the chart and copy the slider value over to the chart when editing has finished.

Comment: Am investigating - many thanks.